# Prep-ending href and src attributes with relative protocols based on document's distance from root?

Tags: javascript, apache, http, url

Building on Paul Irish's HTML5BP protocol specific urls, I want to implement path dependent relative urls, in the sense that the "relativity" of the path to another media/page within the same depends on the current document's distance from the root.

**For example;**

I have all my includes (css/images/js) located at `http://www.example.com/cdn/`, and I have several pages which include them at `http://www.example.com/level-1/level-2/level-3/`.

That's 3 levels below the root folder, which means I need `../../../` three levels of relative protocol prefixed (not sure what `../` is called technically).

Rather than add `../../../` to each `href` or `src`, I'd much rather use javascript to prep-end the correct amount of relative protocol to the url based on the document's current path.

I was planning on using the `document.window.location` object, however when using it on jsFiddle I realized that it returned the href `http://fiddle.jshell.net` which is not the url displayed in the browser.

**On to my two part question:**

A) Is it safe to use the `document.window.location` object in this manner if I'm building a theme/template that will be installed by multiple users (however all with a LAMP set-up).

B) Do any popular libraries exist that already do this?

***TL:DR;** How do I change a `href` or `src` contained url's, relative protocol (`../`) based on the current document's distance from the root (path level)?*

**Any and all answers would be greatly appreciated!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`location.pathname.match(/\//g).length` returns amount of slashes used in url

`document` doesn't have `window` property (at least in Firefox on this site).

jsfiddle uses iframes for each block, thus you may need `window.top.location` instead of `window.location`

Hope, this is enough for solving your problem.

Comment: Brilliant answer :). I've noticed that `document` doesn't have a `window` property when I attempted to run a script on my site just now which was interesting. I didn't realize that `window` was an object of it's own. In any case, thanks :).